# verifying "dyld_sim_shared_cache_arm64" when debugging flutter app in macOS

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio

Today when I start debugging the flutter(2.10.3) app, the macOS Monerey 12.3 shows info like this:

```
verifying "dyld_sim_shared_cache_arm64"
```

and the verify popup window could not complete for hours. It look like this:

[image]

why show this window? what should I do to fix it? This is the flutter env:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale en-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[!] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 1):

update_dyld_shared_cache is depreciate on macOS Monterey (my case 12.3.1). It makes flutter (2.10.4) cannot update. Let wait for new version of flutter to not request update.